# Where is the source code to the "Ubuntu Apps Directory"?

Tags: source-code, websites

i want to make an web based offline package installer that combine Ubuntu Apps Directory, Apt Web, and some automated installer script

Does anyone know where can i find [Ubuntu Apps Directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/) source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The project for this on launchpad is at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-webcatalog

You can get the source by running `bzr branch lp:ubuntu-webcatalog`